# Unsure how to link Variables from a none main class to the main class from objects.

Tags: java, input, constructor

I have 2 Java classes , one is the Main (duh) and the other is where i have blocked or stepped out the code to run.

Main

```
public class W_CS230_Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    String content = new String();
    int count=1;
    File file2 = new File("/Users/kilown/Downloads/contributors.csv");
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file2));
        while (sc.hasNextLine()){
            content = sc.nextLine();
            list.add(content);
            }
        sc.close();
            }catch(FileNotFoundException fnf){
                    fnf.printStackTrace();
            }
        catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("\nProgram terminated Safely...");
            }

        Collections.reverse(list);
        Iterator i = list.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print( (count++) );
            System.out.println(i.next());
            System.out.println("\n");
}




    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);    
        int choice;


           System.out.println("\n");
           System.out.println("Welcome User: ");
           System.out.println("Please select your option: ");
           System.out.println("1: Display current list of Contributors: ");
           System.out.println("2: Enter new Contributor: ");
           System.out.println("3: Save File: ");
           System.out.println("4: NDY Pop: ");
           System.out.println("5: NDY (Not Developed Yet)");
           System.out.println("6: NDY (Not Developed Yet)");
           System.out.println("7: Exit: ");
           System.out.println("\n");
           // System.out.println("4: show stats");
           choice = in.nextInt();



    while (choice !=7){
        if (choice == 1){
            //Read CSV file
            System.out.println("The current list of Contributors: ");
            //function from other class
            readFile.readFile();
            System.out.println("\n");
            E2.selection();
            in.nextLine();
            choice = in.nextInt();

        }
        if (choice == 2){
            // Create stack and input new member into csv file
            System.out.println("Choice 2");
            //function from other class
            E2.userInfo();
            System.out.println("\n");
            E2.selection();
            in.nextLine();
            choice = in.nextInt();

        }
        if (choice == 3){
            System.out.println("choice 3");
            //function from other class
            E2.writeFile();
            System.out.println("\n");
            E2.selection();
            in.nextLine();
            choice = in.nextInt();
        }
        if (choice == 4){
            System.out.println("Choice 4");
            //function from other class
            System.out.println("\n");
            E2.selection();
            in.nextLine();
            choice = in.nextInt();
        }
        if (choice == 5){
            System.out.println("choice 5");
            //function from other class
            System.out.println("\n");
            E2.selection();
            in.nextLine();
            choice = in.nextInt();
        }
        if (choice == 6){
            System.out.println("Choice 6");
            //function from other class
            System.out.println("\n");
            E2.selection();
            in.nextLine();
            choice = in.nextInt();
        }

        // Exit statement for selection 7 
        //System.out.println("W_CS230_Main.java just ran");
        System.out.println("Safely ended application.");
        in.close();
    }


}
}
  //
```

Stepped out

```
public class E2{



// Public Class works Do not change info
public static void readFile(){
    //Read.readFile();
         //choice = in.nextInt();
         //in.nextLine();

           String fileName = "/Users/kilown/Downloads/contributors.csv";
           File file = new File(fileName);


    try {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
        while (inputStream.hasNext()){
            String data = inputStream.next();
            System.out.println(data + "\n");

        }
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(readFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
}
   public static void selection(){

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);    
        int choice;



           System.out.println("Welcome User: ");
           System.out.println("Please select your option:");
           System.out.println("1: input new contributor ");
           System.out.println("2: read selected file");
           System.out.println("3: Save File");
           System.out.println("4: Pop");
           System.out.println("5: Exit");
           // System.out.println("4: show stats");
           choice = in.nextInt();
}
public static void writeFile() throws IOException{
    File contList = new File("Contributor.csv");

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(contList, true);
    BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(buffer);



    if (contList.exists() == false){
        contList.createNewFile();
        System.out.println("file created");
    }else {
        System.out.println("file already exist");
    }
    printWriter.println("scanner information");
    printWriter.close();

}
public static void userInfo(){
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter first and last name: ");
    String city = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter "+name+ " city: ");
    String country = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter "+name+" country: ");

    System.out.print(name);
    System.out.print(city);
    System.out.print(country);


}
public static void sortStack(){
    public Stack<Integer> sort(Stack<Integer> a) {
        a.sort(new Comparator<Integer>());

        public int compare(Integer contID1, Integer ContID2){
            return contID2.compare(contID1);


        }
    });

return a;
}


}

}
```

What I like to do is call lets say 'name' from E2.userInput and have it in a output in Main.

I need all these items in userInput to be seen in Main.

Next I need help with the sorting of the stack, I have not made a rand for the contID but will do when the users are created. the sort i like to happen after the contributor has been created (into a stack or linked list - yet again not sure which one is best).

thanks in advance (yes this is for a College class)